# Why does the program in container sometimes fail to write data to directory /tmp?

Tags: java, linux, docker, containers

I have a java program running in a docker container, and when the program load the Snappy class, it will copies the `.so` file from the Snappy package, to the `/tmp` directory. However, when copying, I got a `FileNotFoundException` exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/snappy-1.1.7-8f76c89c-697a-454d-948c-48d42ab95ffe-libsnappyjava.so (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.extractLibraryFile(SnappyLoader.java:239)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.findNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:355)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SnappyLoader.java:176)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyLoader.loadSnappyApi(SnappyLoader.java:154)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.<clinit>(Snappy.java:47)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:99)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:91)
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyOutputStream.<init>(SnappyOutputStream.java:81)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.CompressionType$3.wrapForOutput(CompressionType.java:81)
```

The strange thing is that this exception happens occasionally. Normally, when copying, if the file doesn't exist, it will create the file, but now the `FileNotFoundException` error appears, so this means that the output file creation has failed. I don't understand why it suddenly fails to create a file under directory `/tmp`， because there is enough disk space？

Dockerfile

```
FROM nexus.sux.cn/alpine-oraclejdk8-test:8u221v1

WORKDIR /opt/

ENV WAR=app.war \
    ENV=test

COPY start.sh* build/libs/${WAR} /opt/
RUN chmod +x start.sh

CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

start.sh

```
exec java ${JAVA_OPTS} \
   ${JVM_OPTS} \
   -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError \
   -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError \
   -XX:HeapDumpPath=${LOG_DIR}/ \=
   -XX:ErrorFile=log.err \
   -jar ${WAR} 1>/dev/null 2>>log.err
```

kubernetes deployment yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: app
  namespace: test
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app
    spec:
      containers:
        envFrom:
        - configMapRef:
            name: global-config
        image: registry.cn-usa.aliyuncs.com/xsio/app:master
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3310
          name: web
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: 4Gi
          requests:
            cpu: 512m
            memory: 1Gi
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/log/stash
          name: log-volume
        - mountPath: /var/tmp
          name: tmp-volume
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-volume
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - hostPath:
          path: /opt/log/stash
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
        name: log-volume
      - hostPath:
          path: /opt/tmp
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
        name: tmp-volume
```

Comment: Can  you show your docker compose/ docker run command as well?

Comment: Already Added...

Comment: Please add the command you use to start your container. Worth adding your Dockerfile too.

Comment: Already Added...

Comment: All this looks fine, by any chance have you tried doing an `exec` into pod and tried `ls /tmp`  inside your pod?

Comment: the directory `/tmp` is mounted by volume `tmp-volume`。There are many files in directory `/tmp`

Comment: If there are many files in /tmp already, is there any chance that the file already exists with permissions not writable from your container?